# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token { on line 11

Tags: javascript

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>
Sa here perseritet nje note</TITLE>

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
var notat = new Array(30);
var nr =0;
var numero =0;
document.writeln("Notat e marra nga studentet jane:");
for( var i=0;i<notat.length;i++){
notat[i]=Math.floor(Math.random() * (11 - 4)) + 4;
document.writeln(""+notat[i]+"");}
var a = prompt("Vendosni noten per te cilen kerkoni informacion", "Vendosni noten ketu");
var elementi =parseInt(a);
While(nr<30)  {
 if(elementi==notat[nr])
 numero=numero+1;
 nr++;}

 alert("Nota " + elementi + "\neshte shfaqur" +""+numero);

</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

This is the code. I cant find out what is wrong with it. The javascript edditor gives the problem above but I do not understand what is wrong. IS something wrong with while loop?
I am a begginer and I really need some help. Thanks

Comment: JavaScript is case-sensitive, it's `while` not `While`!

Answer (score 1):

You write `While` instead of `while`. JavaScript is case-sensitive and only recognizes the lowercase variant as a loop. All names and keywords are case-insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
<script >
    var notat = new Array(30);
    var nr =0;
    var numero =0;
    document.writeln("Notat e marra nga studentet jane:");
    for( var i=0;i<notat.length;i++)
    {
        notat[i]=Math.floor(Math.random() * (11 - 4)) + 4;
        document.writeln(""+notat[i]+"");
    };
    var a = prompt("Vendosni noten per te cilen kerkoni informacion", "Vendosni noten ketu");
    var elementi =parseInt(a);
    while(nr<30)//change this
    {
        if(elementi==notat[nr])
        {
            numero = numero + 1;
            nr++;
        }
    };

    alert("Nota " + elementi + "\neshte shfaqur" +""+numero);

</script>
```

log to your **console**(Firefox is best), It **show all the Error**